# Is there a way to add a cursor to a specific line number in vs code without the mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I really like the multiple cursor option in vs code.

With the mouse I can just Alt + Click any line I want to add a cursor to that specific line.

My question is if there is a way to do this with the key board?  I have tried selecting current line and Ctrl + G to go to a specific line number, but then I lose my initial selection.  I would like to have a cursor on the current line plus any line I choose at same time without using the mouse.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I tried a quick google search and searching here in SO, didn't see anything for this specifically.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-multi-cursor-with-keyboard) you can modify a Multi Cursor with the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly!  I added a Ctrl + Alt + G key binding to selectby.lineNr and I just paste in 'n == c || n == ' and type the line number I need and I'm good!  I tried to upvote you but SO won't allow me yet.